# Javascript async functions in loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have following code with async function download_file(), its working correctly only where runs as single, but in loop, it's not waiting end of iteration.
https://pastebin.com/PRgJRn9i

```
(async () => {

  for (let year of years) {
    for (let month of months) {
        for (let r of day_rng) {
           await download_file(year, month, r);
          }
    }
  }

})();
```

Comment: Looks like it should work.  How do you invoke it?  You should invoke it with the `await` keyword.

Comment: Oh, it's being invoked immediately. Try adding `await (async () => {`.  Not all versions of node support `await` at the top level, so you may have to refactor a bit.

Answer (score 1):

i am assuming you want each iteration to wait for the `download_file` function to end, if so then your `download_file` function should return a `Promise` that resolved whenever you are done downloading and done writing the contents as per your code, currently its not returning anything so the `await` before it won't do anything.

Comment: How to make such promise?

Comment: something like this:
`return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // your code goes here
  .....
  /// you can pass whatever data you want to resolve or reject if you need any
  /// when everything is done and success 
  resolve()

  /// if error
  reject()
})`

Comment: It's already returning a promise because it's `async`.  Just adding `async` to a function makes it return a promise (even if it's a promise with no value).

Comment: @user2740650 hmm that's true, i didn't see that he defined the `download_file` function as async as well, but if he added an `await` before the self invoking function that will make node wait until all downloads are done, right ? not wait for each one, if that makes sense.

Comment: @opllama yes it would wait for all of them to download, which is I believe the intent since he said it wasn't waiting.  I could have misinterpreted the request.

Comment: @user2740650 after you pointed out that the `download_file` function is actually async as well i feel that his code should have worked if he wants it to wait at each download, i have tried something similar before and it was working.

Comment: Hence my answer saying just to add `await` if he wants it to wait :) .  If I'm interpreting correctly, should be a one-word fix.  It's just that it calls the self invoking function but didn't wait for the returned promise to be resolved before running the rest of the script (which would just exit).

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `await` to make nodejs wait for the result.

```
await (async () => {

  for (let year of years) {
    for (let month of months) {
        for (let r of day_rng) {
           await download_file(year, month, r);
          }
    }
  }

})();
```

Comment: Looks like you need at least Node version 14.3 according to https://medium.com/@pprathameshmore/top-level-await-support-in-node-js-v14-3-0-8af4f4a4d478.